# Why do tomcat 10 send a css as mime type text/html instead of text/css?

Tags: css, tomcat, mime

I am lerning servlets and jsp, in a .jsp file i have a link to a css this:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/BookList.css"></link>

referencing the BookList.css that is on the root of the WebApp.

Firefox told me the BookList.css is not beeing served cose the mime type is "text/html" instead of "text/css".

So i wonder cose is tomcat sending the wrong mime type. What should i configure to solve this problem ?

I try to set the BookList.css into a subdirectory of webapp but tomecat does not serv this file on subdirectory.

I set the mime type on web.xml but nothing change.

Comment: "I set the mime type on web.xml": how? "Firefox told me": what specifically? Questions must provide a [mcve].

Comment: The BookList.jsp contain the link to a BookList.css as follow:                                                  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page errorPage = "Error.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Books Store Application</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/BookList.css"></link>
</head>

Comment: The BookList.css contain:                                                                                                           @charset "utf-8";
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
table {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
The Web.xml contains:                                                                                                         <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>